# what is the exact name for SET NO COUNT ON or SET STATISTICS IO ON Are these called Session Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please help me in getting a complete list of session variables or Local Variables.

I know this may not be the right terminology but I honestly did not find the exact name for these.

Example : SET NO COUNT ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON

I need to know what is NO COUNT ON /STATISTICS IO called ( I know what they do but what are they called so that I can search from MSDN a comprehensive list)
I know the functionality of SET NO COUNT ON or SET STATISTICS IO ON but what exactly are they called
Session Variables or Predefined Local Variables.
I wanted to get complete list which are in SQL server

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) they are called *Set statements*

Comment: `SET NO COUNT ON;` isn't valid syntax. It's `SET NOCOUNT ON;`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation they are called [Set statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), and the things they "set" are called "settings" or "options".